# Django keep different database setting in each servers

Tags: python, django, capistrano

I am deploying [`capistrano`](https://capistranorb.com/) to Django project.

And database settings differs from `local` to `server`.

So at first I set linked_files in deploy.rb.

`append :linked_files, "app/settings.py"`

With this setting, deployment doesn't update the `app/settings.py` on server.

However sometimes, I need to add app setting to this file, so it should be synced to server's.

Is there any good practice to deploy django project by tools and keep only database setting in each server??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such setups one way could be to use `app/settings/local.local` and `app/settings/prod.py` files. a make target should copy the `app/settings/local.local` file to `app/settings/local.py` and use this file. This way in settings you always have one .py file. all the changes to local.local are synced with git.

local.py should be added to gitignore. `__init__.py` in settings folder should import from all the py files.

settings
  |
  | -- `__init__`.py
  | -- local.local
  | -- prod.py

somethings like this.